# Insert Space Between Adjacent Tables

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting, lists

At the moment, I effectively have one large table containing what should be multiple smaller tables. That is, my formatting needs improvement. Either way, I currently have one table with 9 columns, 3 rows. The 9 columns are split into 3 column sections. What I want is for the gap between each of those 3 column sections to adjust so the width of all tables (or the single large table depending how you look at it) is equal to the page width. Currently they are all together at the center.

This is what I have currently:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
%\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Computer Language}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tools}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Hardware}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}\cmidrule(l){7-9}
%\midrule
C \& C++ & Java & Python & item & item & item & item & item & item\\
MIPS Assembly & Bash & Verilog & something & item & item & item & item & item \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, is it possible to add bullets to each item as well in this format? Perhaps a different layout entirely would be better suited. Suggestions are welcome.

My explanation may be a bit convoluted so if further explanation is necessary, let me know.

Comment: Please use a complete MWE that contains the ``\documentclass``, all the ``\usepackages`` (and libraries if you use ``tikz`` or something like that), as well as the ``\begin{document}`` and ``\end{document}``. Please refer to [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl) and to [this](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)

Comment: What exactly does 'adjacent  tables'  refer to? Currently, your code only contains one tabular environment.

Comment: @Vinccool96 Fixed.

Comment: @leandriis That's correct, 'adjacent tables' refers more to the three 'sections' of this single table, i.e. Computer Languages, Tools, and Hardware.

Comment: @hotelmariofan: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Personally, I would split the tabular into three separate tabular environments and use something like `\qquad` inbetween them. You could also use somehting like `{lll@{\hskip 10pt}lll@{\hskip 10pt}lll}` but this will change the length of the `\cmidrule`s and change the alignment of the multicolumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution where I split up the table into three `tabular` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Computer Language}}\\
\midrule
C \& C++ & Java & Python \\
MIPS Assembly & Bash & Verilog\\
\end{tabular} \qquad
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tools}}\\
\midrule
item & item & item \\
item & item & item \\
\end{tabular} \qquad
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Hardware}}\\
\midrule
item & item & item \\
item & item & item \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you reeplace `\qquad` with `\hfill` the distance is automatically adjusted to be as large as possible while still fitting inot one page. The result is shown in the following image (red lines indicate the margin):

[image]

Comment: Aha, this is exactly what I was going for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, based on `tabularx` and `geometry`??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=0.98\hsize\RaggedRight \arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=0.98\hsize\RaggedRight \arraybackslash\textbullet~}X}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=1.16\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}XYY*{2}{!{\quad}ZZZ}}
%\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Computer Language}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tools}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Hardware}} \\
\cmidrule(r{1.5em}){1-3}\cmidrule(lr{1.5em}){4-6}\cmidrule(lr{1.5em}){7-9}
%Methods & {Time [\si{\second}]} & {RunCount} & {Time [\si{\second}]} & {RunCount} \\
%\midrule
C \& C++ & Java & Python & item & item & item & item & item & item\\
MIPS Assembly & Bash & Verilog & some\-thing & item & item & item & item & item \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add empty columns if you don't want to split into separate tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lllclllclll}
%\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Computer Language}} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tools}} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Hardware}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(l){5-7}\cmidrule(l){9-11}
%\midrule
C \& C++ & Java & Python && item & item & item && item & item & item\\
MIPS Assembly & Bash & Verilog && something & item & item && item & item & item \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

If you want to increase (or decrease) the amount of extra space you can replace the `c`s with `c@{\hskip 1cm}`, or whatever length you want.

Alternatively, if you want to push the tables to the page margins, you can split into separate tables and use `\hfill`.

[image]

But if the tables are too wide, this will push the third table to the next line.

Comment: If I were to split it into separate tables, would it be possible to have the spacing auto-adjust dependent on the size of the three tables? I would just like the spacing to be as large as possible without kicking one of them tables to a new line.

Comment: Yes. Please see my edit.